# web.py and how to use section blocks

Tags: python, web.py

I use web.py Templator for my project and using the render('templates', base="") I combine a base layout with a page specific layout (simplified).

```
view.py
render = web.template.render('templates',base='layout')
return render.index()
```

shared layout file

```
layout.html
$def with (content)
<html>
<head>
<title>$content.title</title>
</head>
<body>
$:content
</body>
</html>
```

page specific template

```
index.html
$def with (values)
$var title: Hello Kitty
<p>Hello $values, how are you doin?</p>
```

The solution I'm looking for is how to achieve the following

```
login.html
$def with (values)
$var title: Enter credentials

<form>
<p><input type="text" name="user_name"></p>
<p><input type="password" name="user_pwd"></p>
<p><button type="submit">Open the gates</button></p>
</form>

$block_begin
<script>
// When the form is submitted, check the required fields and inform user
// if any data is missing or looks weird
</script>
$block_end

</body>
</html>
```

My question is, how do I add the script to the login.html template but not the index.html template? I'm not interested in having to add all JS logic to all pages, I would like to add this $block_begin/$block_end so that it appears at the bottom of the layout.html like this

```
layout.html
$def with (content)
<html>
<head>
<title>$content.title</title>
</head>
<body>
$:content

$block_begin
$block_end
</body>
</html>
```

The $block_begin/$block_end was just something I came up with to better explain myself.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear, `template -> defwith sections` is a grammar, not an example. To use templates, check http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/templetor for examples.

At a high level, you create templates similar to

```
=== templates/index.html ===
$def with(values)
$var title: Hello Kitty
<p>Hello $values, how are you doin?</p>

=== templates/layout.html ===
$def with(content)
<html>
 <head>
  <title>$content.title</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  $:content
 </body>
</html>
```

Then in your python you **render** the template, passing in any parameters specified in the template. ("`values`" in this example.) The named template (`index.html`) is render using the base (`layout.html`), and as you've discovered, `content` contains the rendered internal bit (the results of index) and is inserted into the base template, layout.

You're asking how to get some script into login.html, but not in index.html & that's easy: just add the javascript code into the login.html template.

```
=== login.html ===
$def with (values)
$var title: Enter credentials
<form>
...
</form>
<script>
  window.addEventListener('load', function () {
     // whatever javascript you want to execute on load.
     // If using jQuery, you'll have to use $$('form') or jQuery('form') rather
     // than $('form'), as dollar signs are special within the template.
  });
</script>
```

Something more clever? Use `content` more fully. Anything you define using `$var` in your template gets put into `$content` in the base layout.

If you want to include `login.js` only when your `login.html` page is rendered, you could simple create a new content attribute. In login.html:

```
$var extra_js: js/login.js
```

Then, in your layout file conditionally load the value at the bottom (where we like to load scripts).

```
=== templates/layout.html ===
...
<body>
  $:content
  $if content.get('extra_js', None):
      <script type="text/javascript" src="$content.extra_js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can make your layout.html more and more powerful, parameterizing meta data, scripts, css files, etc. Just like you did with `$content.title`, and let your individual template files drive different parts of the overall layout.

Comment: Which is what Im during. But the thing I would like, is to define a block inside the layout file that I can then add content to depending on the view loader. Like it's possible with Django templates and Jinja, but I'd like to stick with web.py's templator for this instead of switching. So the question is, is that feature supported

Comment: I'm sure it's possible, but I don't understand what you're trying to do that isn't working. web.py Templator doesn't need or require `{% %}` blocks, as you can directly add the javascript to the template. (Either `<script src=...></script>` or `<script>var foo="bar";</script>`). Can you provide more detail as to what you're trying to do?

Comment: For example, common-look-and-feel, is done by using `base=` in render. You can have templates call/load other templates by calling `render` directly in the template (it's python, after all)... I think that may be what you're looking for.